# Rockettheme template sidebar malfunctioning

Tags: html, css, templates, joomla, themes

Recently I got called in to work on a site (one that I did not build) at northviewstallions.com. Apparently the designer used the Rockettheme template Ionosphere and is running Joomla! 2.5. Everything was working fine until last week and for no apparent reason the layout decided to malfunction. Now for whatever reason site container div's aren't expanding with the content and the sidebar is shoved under the main div. I'm tearing my hair out over here, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!
Nick

Answer (score 0):

So one of the Rockettheme mods helped me out, figured I'd share the answer here unless anyone comes looking.

The site owner had installed the JCE editor in the backend for easier article creation. Turns out that using the "Read More" button without pressing enter first causes the editor to close a div tag that isn't open. So you're unknowingly closing one of the parent divs. Hope this helps someone, even though this isn't the correct forum for the question.